# Polymaps.org & KML / Plotting lines in GeoJSON

Tags: kml, georss, geojson

Has anyone had a play with the Polymaps.org KML parser? To me it seems the example doesn't even work.

I have an existing KML file which is being generated from a very simple database - I have a placemark name, and a lat/long in decimal notation for said placemark. I have hundreds of these, that form a route - What I want to do is very simple, and Polymaps is perfect, but there are limited GeoJSON examples, and even more limited Polymaps examples.

Are there any GeoJSON experts that could lend a hand? I basically want to create a GeoJSON stream which takes my placemark name, lat & long and creates a line to form a route.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried the KML parser, but here's an example of working with Geoserver geoJSON

```
<style>
.layer path { fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2;}
.layer circle { fill: lightcoral; fill-opacity: .5; stroke: brown; }
</style>

<script>
function myCallback(data)    {
    po = org.polymaps;
    map = po.map()
        .container(document.getElementById("map").appendChild(po.svg("svg")))
        .center({
            lat:(data.bbox[1] + (data.bbox[3]-data.bbox[1])/2),
            lon:(data.bbox[0] + (data.bbox[2]-data.bbox[0])/2)
        })
        .zoom(15)
        .add(po.interact());

    // points
    map.add(po.geoJson().features( data.features ));

    // make path
    var paths=[];
    for (var i=0;i<data.features.length;i++)    
        paths.push(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates);

    map.add(po.geoJson()
        .features([{"geometry":{"coordinates":paths, "type": "LineString"}}]));
}


var client = document.createElement("script");
client.src = 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/ows?'+
    'service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature'+
    '&typeName=tiger:poi&maxFeatures=50'+
    '&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:myCallback';

document.body.appendChild(client);
</script>
```